# Async await Future.delayed in dart

Tags: dart

I am having trouble understanding  why one  piece of code prints the future is null

```dart
void main() async {
  task1();
  String str = await task2();
  task3(str);
}

void task1() {
  print('ring');
}

Future<String> task2() async {
  Duration dur = Duration(seconds: 3);
  String res;
  await Future.delayed(dur, () {
    res = 'a bright one!';
    return res; // return statement inside the callback.
  });
  
}

void task3(String str) {
  print('the future is $str');
}
```

while this works properly and has the expected behavior of printing 'the future is a bright one'

```dart
void main() async {
  task1();
  String str = await task2();
  task3(str);
}

void task1() {
  print('ring');
}

Future<String> task2() async {
  Duration dur = Duration(seconds: 3);
  String res;
  await Future.delayed(dur, () {
    res = 'a bright one!';
  });
  return res;
}

void task3(String str) {
  print('the future is $str');
}
```

I am new to asynchronous programming  but my understanding is that the callback that is the second argument in Future.delayed is executed after a delay what I don't understand why the placement of the return statement here breaks the code. I tried to run the code in debug mode to trace the code but I didn't understand what is exactly happening. All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your first version discards the value returned by the callback.  Returning from a callback doesn't magically make the caller return that value.  The caller needs to explicitly return it: `return await Future.delayed(...);`.

Comment: Oh just realized that the return inside the callback is just for the callback. My bad that was a massive oversight.